# WebClient save data to Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I retrieved some data about clients from external api using WebClient. Now I want to save it to MongoDb, but struggling with it. Here how I retrieved the data:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        RequestDTO requestBody = new RequestDTO("getClients", new RequestDataDto("1", "60"));

        ProductWrapperMars response = client.post()
                .uri(new URI("MyURL"))
                .header("token", "MyToken") //I have a header as well
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(requestBody)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ClientList.class)
                .block();       
    }
}
```

Here is how Client class looks like:

```
public class ClientList {

    
    private Boolean available;
    private List<Clients> data;

}


public class Clients {

    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp date;

//getters and setters
}
```

How should I organize the saving of retrieved data to Mongo?

Comment: You can try using `ReactiveMongoRepository` _or_ `ReactiveMongoTemplate` API for persisting to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

To save to mongo DB:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-reactivestreams</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Configure db using `SimpleReactiveMongoDatabaseFactory`

use `ReactiveMongoRepository` or `ReactiveMongoTemplate` .

They have almost similar interface like our non-reative `MongoDatabase`